# Is it possible to play video in HTML with a private video stored in AWS S3?

Tags: html, amazon-s3

When the resources are public there's no problem, but I want to improve the security on the stored resources, so I thought I can **Block all public access** to my bucket.  Then, I could only access those resources with authenticated API calls. At this point there's no problem, I can still download those files using my API Keys. But, I also need to be able to reproduce stored videos.

The simplest way I know is to use the **HTML *video* Tag** where you only configure the **src** property. It's clear that the video won't be loaded because it is blocked and I need to authenticate myself in order to access it. But I cannot set my credentials here. how can I do it? Is there any video player which do this authentication stuff?

I can modify the bucket policy to allow my site to access these resources, but I don't know if I'm really securying the stored resources. If someone knows the URL of some file (maybe by bruteforce), downloading that file via my site would be so easy. What I need is that those resources are pretty safe, and no one can even reach them but the owner of these files, because they may contain confidential info.

Comment: AWS S3 allow you creating a presigned request, with an expiration timestamp, it's almost safe, but it can be shared and valid during it validity. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to simply have a separate independent S3 bucket exclusively for public assets (such as a video, which will always be public by nature).

It's [also possible](https://advancedweb.hu/how-s3-signed-urls-work/) to load a video in a private bucket, and to accomplish this you're looking for what's known as a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).

This can be called through JavaScript, using the AWS SDK:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
const params = {Bucket: 'XXXXX', Key: 'XXXXX'};
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
```

Or created with the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 presign s3://awsexamplebucket/test2.txt
```

This will generate a URL which lasts for the default 1 hour, and can be directly referenced in HTML:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/file_name.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXX&Expires=XXXXX&Signature=XXXXX
```

To specify a custom timeframe, just add the `--expires-in` flag:

```
aws s3 presign s3://awsexamplebucket/test2.txt --expires-in 604800
```

Comment: The url is for a limited time. I want to display the video for as long as the user is active on the page - could be 1 hr/24hrs or whatever. What can I do in such a case?

Comment: @jsdbt, you can have an approach similar to access token / refresh token. To keep things secure, you can generate a signed url for a shorter period. Then on the active page, refresh that url silently.